# How to retrieve table names from database in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to retrieve table names from the database.  I am using the phpmyadmin database. What query should be used?

Comment: Not specific to PHP5, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [**MySQL show tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) as:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM db_name
```

Output of `SHOW TABLES` contains a *single column of table names*.